# JavaScript order all other child elements by attribute but (this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, dom

I don't want to clutter this question with code. So here's my fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/jaisfiddles/acdk1aLL/5/

And here is embedded demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().prepend($(this));
        var childDivs = $("div.tabs");
        for (var i = 1;i<childDivs.length;i++){
            $(childDivs[i]).addClass('sort');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
    <div id="vert-navbar">
        <div id="tab1" class="tabs"><p>TAB1</p></div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tabs"><p>TAB2</p></div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tabs"><p>TAB3</p></div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tabs"><p>TAB4</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content"></div>
</div>
```

The intention is to move a clicked-on DIV to top and sort all other child DIVs in alphabetical order. Eg. If TAB 3 is clicked on, move TAB 3 to top. And reorder the rest as TAB1, TAB2, TAB4. I've managed to bring the selection to the top using

```
    $(this).parent().prepend($(this));
```

This may seem sorted but not really.

So, I thought I'd create an array of elements (starting at 1 not 0 to get all elements starting with the second one)  by assigning them a classname 'sort' as you'll see on the fiddle. And sort this array and append the parent DIV - vert-navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort *first* and then append. This way it is guarantied that the order is correct after you move clicked item to the top:

```js
var $tabs = $(".tabs").on('click', function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $tabs.sort().appendTo($parent);
    $parent.prepend($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
    <div id="vert-navbar">
        <div id="tab1" class="tabs"><p>TAB1</p></div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tabs"><p>TAB2</p></div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tabs"><p>TAB3</p></div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tabs"><p>TAB4</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first reset the block arrangement on each click event then just prepend the clicked div to the parent

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs").on('click', function() {
        reset();
        $(this).parent().prepend($(this));

    });
});
function reset(){
    var childDivs = $("div.tabs");
    for (var i = childDivs.length;i>0;i--){
        $("#vert-navbar").prepend($("#tab"+i));
    }
}
```

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vwfe67k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".tabs").on('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().prepend($(this));
            var orderlist = $("#vert-navbar .tabs").slice(1).sort(function(a,b){
                if($(a).find("p").text()<$(b).find("p").text()){
                    return -1;
                }
                else if($(a).find("p").text()>$(b).find("p").text()){
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
            orderlist.splice(0,0,$("#vert-navbar .tabs").eq(0)[0]);
            $("#vert-navbar").append(orderlist);
        });
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/acdk1aLL/6/

Reorder the rest of the list and then add new first element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sort` method on the remainder of the tabs and then `append` them to the parent of the clicked element as follows.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs").on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().prepend( $(this) )
        .append( 
          $("div.tabs").not( this ).sort(function(a,b) { 
            return $('p',a).text() > $('p',b).text() ? 1 : 
            $('p',b).text() > $('p',a).text() ? -1 : 0; 
          })
        );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
    <div id="vert-navbar">
        <div id="tab1" class="tabs"><p>TAB1</p></div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tabs"><p>TAB2</p></div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tabs"><p>TAB3</p></div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tabs"><p>TAB4</p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="main-content"></div>
</div>
```